# Logging (lots of) Gmail Data into a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets, google-apps

The object of my Google App Script is to log all basic data from email within a certain range of time (not yet implemented), from within all labels, into a Google Sheet.

This currently works to a limited degree. It will collect a small number of emails, but if I increase this (I have a lot of emails to log), this code will either `‘Exceeded maximum execution time’` if I pause for 500 or 1000 milliseconds (as below), otherwise I hit the other ratemax quota `Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.`

In the code below, I believe I attempted to repeat the main FOR loop 20 times with a WHILE loop, this was a way of seeing if I could perform this single grab n load `var labelThreads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads(start, 1)`, 20 times. This would be one way to begin tracking "batches" -- It didn't quite work and I believe there is a better way to approach this, need some help.

```
function whenV24() {  
  function setColumnNames(range, columnNames){
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(range);
    cell.setValues(columnNames);
  }
  setColumnNames("A1:G1", [["Date","Label","To","From","Subject","Body","File Names"]]);
  betterGetV24();
}



  function betterGetV24() {
  var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 

  // ** LABEL NAME COLLECTION **  
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();

  // ** CREATE EMPTY DATA ARRAYS **
  var emailFrom = [];
  var emailTo = [];
  var emailBody = [];
  var emailDate = [];
  var emailLabel = [];
  var emailSubject = [];

  // ** LOAD "INBOX EMAIL DATA" INTO EMPTY ARRAYS **
  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    emailBody.push([" "]);    
    emailFrom.push([messages[i][0].getFrom()]);
    emailTo.push([messages[i][0].getTo()]);
    emailSubject.push([messages[i][0].getSubject()]);
    emailDate.push([Utilities.formatDate(messages[i][0].getDate(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")]);
    emailLabel.push(["Inbox"]);
  };

  // ** LOAD "LABELED EMAIL DATA" INTO EMPTY ARRAYS **
  for (var l = 0; l < labels.length; l++) {                                       // ** Runs a for-loop over "labels array". 
      var label = labels[l].getName();                                            //    Gets "this" label name.       
      var start = 0; // sets start number as 0
      var tracker = 0;


    // this section of code has to loop based on a separate set of logic
    while (start < 20){
      tracker++;
      Logger.log("tracker :" + tracker);
        var labelThreads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads(start, 1); //    Gets threads in "this" label. (*Set Limits Here*) 
        var labelMessages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(labelThreads);         //    Gets array with each email from "this" thread. 


        Utilities.sleep(500);       // pause in the loop for 500 milliseconds

        for (var t = 0; t <labelThreads.length; t++){                                 // ** Runs a for-loop over threads in a label. 
            Logger.log("part 1 - inside for-loop over message number: " + labelMessages[t][0].getId());
            Utilities.sleep(500);// **pause in the loop for 500 milliseconds

          if (labelMessages[t] == undefined){}      // If it's empty, skip.
            else {                                  // If it's not empty.
              Logger.log("part 2 - inside if statement in for-loop > push emailData into arrays");

              emailBody.push([" "]);    
              emailFrom.push([labelMessages[t][0].getFrom()]);
              emailTo.push([labelMessages[t][0].getTo()]);        
              emailDate.push([Utilities.formatDate(labelMessages[t][0].getDate(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")]);
              emailSubject.push([labelMessages[t][0].getSubject()]);
              emailLabel.push([labels[l].getName()]);
              mysheet.getRange(2,2,emailLabel.length,1).setValues(emailLabel);
          }
       }
      Logger.log("part 3 - outside if statement -> start += 2")
      var start = start + 3;
    }
      Logger.log("part 4 - outside while loop"); 

  }
  // ** THEN, LOG THE FILLED DATA ARRAYS TO ROWS **
  //getSheetValues(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns)
  mysheet.getRange(2,4,emailFrom.length,1).setValues(emailFrom);
  mysheet.getRange(2,3,emailTo.length,1).setValues(emailTo);
  mysheet.getRange(2,1,emailDate.length,1).setValues(emailDate);
  mysheet.getRange(2,5,emailSubject.length,1).setValues(emailSubject);
  mysheet.getRange(2,6,emailBody.length,1).setValues(emailBody);
}
```

I think at this point I should be using triggers, but it seems like I also have to track the previous batch of emails-logged and continue to the next batch. I'm also not aware of how to tie this in with triggers.

Thanks for reading. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I was setting data to the spreadsheet incorrectly here. For each loop I was trying to set data in the spreadsheet. I'm not sure how I ended up doing that. Simply moving this out of the loop and setting it later fixed my issue. updated code here: http://pastie.org/9793256#96,100,109,117,123-125,131,135-139

```
    for (var t = 0; t <labelThreads.length; t++){                                 // ** Runs a for-loop over threads in a label. 
                    Logger.log("part 1 - inside for-loop over message number: " + labelMessages[t][0].getId());
                    Utilities.sleep(500);// **pause in the loop for 500 milliseconds

                  if (labelMessages[t] == undefined){}      // If it's empty, skip.
                    else {                                  // If it's not empty.
                      Logger.log("part 2 - inside if statement in for-loop > push emailData into arrays");

                      emailBody.push([" "]);    
                      emailFrom.push([labelMessages[t][0].getFrom()]);
                      emailTo.push([labelMessages[t][0].getTo()]);        
                      emailDate.push([Utilities.formatDate(labelMessages[t][0].getDate(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")]);
                      emailSubject.push([labelMessages[t][0].getSubject()]);
                      emailLabel.push([labels[l].getName()]);

// ** INCORRECTLY TRYING TO SET DATA PER LOOP **
                      mysheet.getRange(2,2,emailLabel.length,1).setValues(emailLabel);
                  }
               }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use PropertiesService to locally store the index of the last processed email. You can then add the "start" parameter to the GmailApp.search() method to begin searching from the last position and set this whole thing to trigger every 5 or 10 minutes.

```
function myTrigger() {
  var start = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("startIndex");
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:inbox", start, 200);
  for (var t in threads) {
     // Log the thread using your existing code
     start++;
  }
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("startIndex", start);
}
```

Comment: I've looked at the code a little but haven't had time to try it, today I have a few hours and will look into this. Thank you very much for the suggestion!

Comment: Ok, I've looked into this application a bit, and while I think I understand it generally, I am having a hard time implementing it. I think I need to find a working example of how this is done and then try to adapt it. Your example seems too unlike my implementation for me to understand how to use it, at this moment. Still searching